# Select multiple rows having distinct columns with a condiction

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I'm struggling with a query where I want to select all book data rows distincted by some columns.

**My table data:**

```
BookRef    BookFloor   BookSection    Orders    OrderType
-------    ---------   -----------    ------    ---------
   4           7            2          null         1
   4           7            2          null         3
   4           7            2          null         2
   4           7            2           8           2
   4           1            5          null         3
```

For one BookRef, in a BookFloor, in a BookSection, with a distinct OrderType I only want to select the row which have Orders. If there is no orders, I want to select only one row.

**My desired output:**

```
BookRef    BookFloor   BookSection    Orders    OrderType
-------    ---------   -----------    ------    ---------
   4           7            2          null         1
   4           7            2          null         3
   4           7            2           8           2
   4           1            5          null         3
```

I'm trying to use the `HAVING` clause. However it is not working. How can I perform my code to do what I need?

**My query:**

```
select BookRef, BookFloor, BookSection, Orders, OrderType
from #myTempTable
GROUP BY OrderType, Orders, BookSection, BookFloor, BookRef
having count(BookRef) = 1 and count(BookFloor) = 1 and (count(OrderType) = 1 or (count(OrderType) > 1 and count(Orders) = 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `WHERE` clause to solve my problem.

```
select BookRef, BookFloor, BookSection, Orders, OrderType
from #myTempTable
where (select count(a.Id) from #myTempTable a 
         where a.BookRef = t.BookRef and a.BookFloor = t.BookFloor and a.BookSection = t.BookSection and a.OrderType = t.OrderType) = 1
      or t.Orders is not null
```

However I don't know yet if there is a easier way to do the same with the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  One method is:

```
select t.*
from #temp t
where t.OrderType is not null
union all
select t.*
from #temp t
where t.OrderType is null and
      not exists (select 1 from #temp t2 where t2.ordertype = t.ordertype and t2.bookref and t2.booksection = t.booksection and t2.bookfloor = t.bookfloor and t2.ordertype is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would also use `GROUP BY`:

```
select BookRef, BookFloor, BookSection, max(Orders) Orders, OrderType
from #myTempTable
where OrderType is not null -- May be Orders is not null
group by BookRef, BookFloor, BookSection, OrderType;
```

However, `max()` function is redundant here you can directly use this as in `GROUP BY` clause for *uniqueness*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user row_number on partition

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookRef,BookFloor,BookSection,OrderType ORDER BY orders)  AS seq FROM MyTable
) AS t WHERE t.seq=1
```